# How can I recover deleted iWeb and iDVD?

Tags: macos, idvd, iweb

When I got my MacBook Pro (1st version) last week on OS X Yosemite, it came with iWeb and iDVD but I deleted them and now I want them back. I haven't backed up using Time Machine.

Comment: They are probably still there pending how you deleted them.

Comment: i deleted them by going into my finder and deleted n the applications. i just threw them into trash but i emptied my trash

Comment: That is why the trash bucket is there, and it is not to be emptied instantly :(

Answer (score 1):

iWeb and iDVD does not work in Yosemite anyway—crashes immediately on launch.